# Targeting the 3.5 Framework using MSBuild 4.0 Assembly Conflict

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm attempting to create a 3.5 build from a 4.0 set of code.  It almost works the following `msbuild options: /tv:3.5 /p:targetframeworkversion=v3.5`.  The issue is that I get a conflict for those classes that have moved to new assemblies in 4.0, for example:

```
error CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\
GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.W
eb.ApplicationServices.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\
System.Web.dll'
```

How do I tell msbuild to pickup the System.Web assembly?  Can I tell it to ignore the 4.0 directory?

Comment: I'm reporting this via Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597801/msbuild-4-does-not-respect-toolsversion

Comment: Uploaded a detailed log, still no answer...

Comment: I think that is Microsoft for there is a problem, how do we answer it.

Comment: Ok, they are claiming it is resolved by design, I will confirm their work around.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a similar issue to what we had, ended up with Hf from Microsoft

[TFS2008 to TFS2010 migration upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044763/tfs2008-to-tfs2010-migration-upgrade)

Comment: I'll check this off once I get a ping back from MS that it is in fact a bug.

Comment: there dosnt seem to be some dogdyiness from MS about the .net 3.5 interop. Cheers Iain